# Storing return data of print in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am amateur in python. I have this code

```
import csv
csv.register_dialect('piper', delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
with open('temp1.txt','rb') as csvfile:

for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect='piper'):
    print row['ICS_ORIG_STRT_DT']
    print row['EDW_FIRST_OUT_IFP_DT']
    print row['STATE_PROVINCE']
    print row['EFFORT_TYPE']
    print ''
```

Now I want to run an `if` statement to check if the data inside `EFFORT_TYPE` is `'TM'` or not. If `EFFORT_TYPE` returns `'TM'` I want to concatenate some rows together. The data set is below. For `if` statement I have this which is throwing errors.

```
abc = str( [print row['EFFORT_TYPE']])

if abc == 'TM':
    print (row['PRINT_ACCT_NUM']row['CURR_DT'])
else:
    print (row['FIRST_NAME']row['LAST_NAME'])
```

This is the beginning of the input file :

```
SEQ_NUM|ICS_ORIG_STRT_DT|EDW_FIRST_OUT_IFP_DT|CURR_DT|DEV_GE_NUM_DAYS|DEV_LE_NUM_DAYS|FILENAME|CAMPAIGN_NAME_DESC|CAMPAIGN_WAVE|MARKET_SEGMENT|CAMPAIGN_NAME|CAMPAIGN_WAVE_RUN|EFFORT_TYPE|EFFORT_NUM|UU_ID|PRINT_ACCT_NUM|PRINT_PUB_CD|PREFIX|SUFFIX|FIRST_NAME|LAST_NAME|EMAIL|PHONE_NUM|BUS_PHONE|CO_NAME|STREET_NUM|ADDR|ADDR2|CITY|STATE_PROVINCE|ZIP_POSTAL|ZIP4|TRACK_CD|VANITY_URL|BILL_FORM|LETTER_TEXT|OUTER
130|20140401|00010101|20140728|85||Apr14WSJ_CNYR_NOEMAIL_CAP_TM_20140728.txt|Apr14WSJ_CNYR_NOEMAIL_CAP_TM|WSJ_CNYR_NOEMAIL_CAP_TM|CNYR|WSJ_CNYR_NOEMAIL_CAP|Apr14|TM|||032714296269|J|||ARTHUR|MURPHY||9784255147|||46|LANTERN###WAY||SHIRLEY|MA|01464|2136|aaqecw0c||||
```

Comment: Oh dear heavens, do you really need to include *all that text?*

Comment: I don't read it, because it's like spam to a technical question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to indent the code in the if statement and change the condition to
`if 'TM' in abc`.

```
abc = str(row['EFFORT_TYPE'])
if 'TM' in abc:
    print(row['PRINT_ACCT_NUM']+row['CURR_DT'])
else:
    print(row['FIRST_NAME']+row['LAST_NAME'])
```

Comment: @Rajarshi Could you update the questin with the error message?

Comment: there is an error in your program: expected an indented block.and then it is red on the print statement

Comment: Which line gives the error message? Have you indented the two print lines with the same number of whitespace/tabs?

Comment: this line is showing the error in print(row['PRINT_ACCT_NUM']+row['CURR_DT'])

Comment: there was actually blank spaces fixed it.ty guys.

Comment: OK, indentation levels and blocks should be always consistent in python.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `print` in your case - it only prints output, but doesn't convert to string. In Python 2, it is a keyword, so this is **invalid syntax**. In Python 3, it is a function returning `None`, so in your case (except for that you would be missing some parenthesis which leads to a syntax error) it would set `abc` to `"[None]"`, which is probably not what you want. Simply use `str` to convert to string if it is not already a string (which in your case it is). Then, you can use `+` to concatenate the rows:

```
abc = row['EFFORT_TYPE']
if abc == 'TM':
    print(row['PRINT_ACCT_NUM'] + row['CURR_DT'])
else:
    print(row['FIRST_NAME'] + row['LAST_NAME'])
```

In this scenario, you don't even need to use `abc` and can replace `if abc == 'TM':` with `if row['EFFORT_TYPE'] == 'TM':`

Comment: it is not whether the OP needs it, it is invalid syntax.

Comment: it is throwing error expected an indented block. on print.

Comment: What error? This should work on Python 2 and 3. If it is a `KeyError` (my personal guess), it is because `row["KEY"]` (replace `KEY` with the key it fails on) doesn't exist. That is probably a problem with either your data or the way you are loading it

Answer (score 0):

You can directly compare `row['EFFORT_TYPE']` with `'TM'` and use `+` for string concatenation :

```
if row['EFFORT_TYPE'] == 'TM':
    print (row['PRINT_ACCT_NUM'] + row['CURR_DT'])
else:
    print (row['FIRST_NAME'] + row['LAST_NAME'])
```

Comment: this is throwing an error: expected an indented block.the error on the print statement. print(row['PRINT_ACCT_NUM'] + row['CURR_DT'])